# What does this robots.txt mean? Doesn't it allow any robots?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /admin
Sitemap: http://www.myadress.com/ext/sm/Sitemap_114.xml
```

I've found this robots.txt file in one of my website's root folder. I don't know i made it or who.

I think this file does not allow any robots to admin folder. This is good.

But i wonder if this blocks all robots to all files in my website?

I've changed it with this file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://www.myadress.com/ext/sm/Sitemap_114.xml
```

ps: this website is not getting any index for a long time. was the old file problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old script, other than the duplicate /Admin entry, was correct. There is no Allow: command, and an empty 'Disallow:' opens the site up to robots.

http://www.free-seo-news.com/all-about-robots-txt.htm

Specifically, check item #7 under 'Things you should avoid' and #1 under 'Tips and Tricks'

Comment: But this website is not indexing in any engine in any way. never indexing. there are a lot of indexed page but no actions for 2-3 months (i think old robots.txt file was uploaded 2-3 months ago).

Comment: It may be a misconfiguration issue. While a blank `Disallow:` allows access to the whole site, it's only there because at least one `Disallow:` is required. I would leave it out, actually. But remove the `Allow:` statement from the new file. Another good reference: http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. I read your old file the same way you did - that root was being disallowed. Either way, your new robots file is set up how I expect that you want it.

Comment: Sorry but i coundn't understand well. You mean first file was blocking my root file? or not?